# how to make removable media private

Tags: linux

How might it be possible to rig a system such that some removable media, like a USB stick, can be mounted by a user without any need for root privileges, and yet be made private for that user? I'm thinking of some multiuser situation, like a school or library, where there are many terminals. I sit down at a terminal, plug in my USB stick, mount it, without needing any privileges, have full access to it, and yet it is completely private to me. I know I can gain privacy my mounting the stick in my home directory, but I'd need root privileges to make the mount.  In fstab I can use the 'user,noauto' option, which lets me, or anyone else,  mount, OTOH, then, once mounted, the sick is visible to anyone. Is there some way of making the device itself private? chmod'ing the contents is not sufficient since other users can still do things like write new files. I think this should be doable but I'm damned if I can figure it out.

Comment: There is an easy solution. I will answer your question as soon as you start accepting the answers you got for your other questions.

Comment: Pardon? I get the feeling I'm missing something. Of course I accept them, and with thanks. Whenever I'm quite stuck, and all else fails, this is the place to find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue does not lie in the removable media, but rather in the filesystem. The FAT filesystem does not support individual access control.

You can solve your problem by defining default access rights in your fstab. From the manpage:

```
   umask=value
          Set the umask (the bitmask of  the  permissions  that  are  not
          present). The default is the umask of the current process.  The
          value is given in octal.

   dmask=value
          Set the umask applied to directories only.  The default is  the
          umask of the current process.  The value is given in octal.

   fmask=value
          Set  the  umask  applied to regular files only.  The default is
          the umask of the current process.  The value is given in octal.
```

So, e.g. "user,noauto,umask=077" should take all rights away from anybody else then the user performing the mount. Note that this is already the default dmask on most systems! Maybe something is wrong with your setup.

Comment: tty=pts/0 ray hewitt-sda2-LMDE / $  mount /dev/sdd1 
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdd1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

Comment: ypnos,  I thought that was 'them' accepting 'me' not 'me' accepting 'them'. So how do I accept an answer?

Comment: Tried your idea and got the above error. But I like your thinking. Wish I could enter a newline in this box!

Comment: See my second comment to your question, the url there leads to an explanation on how to accept. You need to click on the checkmark below the big vote number. Anyway, you need to post what you wrote into fstab to be able to track down the error.

Comment: Ok, I see the checkmark. I wish it was more self explanatory what it did.  Here's the line in fstab                                   /dev/sdd1              /media/sdd/1        ext4 user,exec,noauto,umask=077    0 0

Comment: format test: <br>    /dev/sdd1              /media/sdd/1        ext4 user,exec,noauto,umask=077    0 0

Comment: Well, obviously the filesystem type should be vfat, not ext4. That's why umask is not a valid option (it is not valid for ext4). If it is really ext4, you would need to fix the permissions in the filesystem directly.

Comment: I don't know why that's 'obvious' this is a linux system so one might expect to use ext4. There's nothing in the umask information I can find that suggests it does not work with ext4, I wish these things were made more clear! Do you know of some doc that will make all this clear?  Anyway, thanks for your help :-)

Comment: The original manpage of 'mount', where I pasted the information from, makes this clear: "Mount options for fat [..]"

Comment: True. I misread the page. I had  it deep in my head that fat has no permissions and ext4 does, so the idea of umasking permissions that don't exist anyway, seemed nonsensical. I see I had it backwards, but it still doesn't make any sense to me how ext4 can *not* be umaskable but fat can.